# Assign all outgoing request a single IP from cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, devops

I have setup a Kubernetes cluster using kops on aws.

It has 4 worker nodes and one master node.

It has deployments for each microservice i.e. customer deployment has two pods

I need to make calls to some API from these pods.

Whenever I make request from these pods the source ip is by default the node's ip.

I want a unified ip address for any outgoing request from the cluster.

I am already using `internet gateway` and `ingress nginx controller` for incoming requests.

Someone suggest to create a `NAT gateway`.

I created and allocated a elastic ip address. Still it's not working and using the node's ip only on which the pod is deployed.

Answer (score 1):

I think the tool you want here is an egress IP. I don't know the specifics for  AWS/kops, but an egress IP has worked for Azure Kubernetes Service for the same situation.